# MVC Asp.net zip file download

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some code in an MVC project that creates a zip file and sends it to the browser. Everything works when I manually enter the URL in the browser, but if I click on the link in the page to get the download, I get a file of a different size and Windows cannot open it.

So, if I manually enter something like this:
http://localhost/fms-ui/File/DownloadZipFile/?id=10&filename=DST-2015-11-14_04_04_04

I get a zip file of 167 bytes and it open fine.

If I click on the link in the page, I get a file of 180 bytes and Windows says the file is corrupted. Hun?

My one stipulation is that I cannot use an external library. Due to politics I must use the library provided with .Net Framework 4.5 (static ZipFile class).

Code:

```
  public FileContentResult DownloadZipFile(int id, string filename)
    {
        /*
         * 1 - get fileset info
         * 2 - get temp file name
         * 3 - create zip file under temp name
         * 4- return file
         */
        QuesterTangent.Wayside.FileServices.FileSet sInfo = new QuesterTangent.Wayside.FileServices.FileSet(id);
        string path = Path.Combine(sInfo.BasePath);

        string tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".zip");

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, tempPath);

        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempPath);

        //System.IO.File.Delete(tempPath); Commented so I can compare the files

        filename = filename + ".zip";

        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = filename,
            Inline = false,
        };
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

        return File(fileBytes, "application/zip");
    }
```

I've tried this with and without AppendHeader and with various contentTypes, but it doesn't seem to effect the outcome.

Here is the JavaScript that calls the controller (I inherited this code but it works for other things).

```
function GetFile(url) {
//spin a wheel for friendly buffering time
var buffer = $('.MiddleRightDiv').spinBuffer();
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: {},
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
        // check for a filename
        var filename = "";
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }

        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });

        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            if (filename) {
                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                // safari doesn't support this yet
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            }
            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
        }
    },
    complete: function (result) {
        if (typeof $('.MiddleRightDiv').spinBuffer !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction($('.MiddleRightDiv').spinBuffer)) {
            $('.MiddleRightDiv').spinBuffer("destroy");
        }
    }
});
```

Any input would be a great help. I have gone over other similar postings but non of them seems to address the core problem I am having.

Thanks,

dinsdale

Comment: Try to change ajax method from "POST" to " GET" (or remove type definition, GET is default)

Comment: Makes no difference. When byte array is read into memory on the controller it's 167 bytes. When it arrives in IE its 180 bytes and it can't be opened. What is happening that could be adding 13 bytes to my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.ajax cannot read bytestreams correctly (check SO for many topics about this), so we have to use old and good XMLHttpRequest. Here is your function refactored to work with blobs. Extened it with fallbacks for other browsers while saveAs(blob,filename) is the draft.

```
function GetFile(url) {
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url);
        req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        req.onload = function (e) {
            if (req.response) {
                var filename = 'archive.zip';
                var disposition = req.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                    if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                }

                var type = req.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

                var blob = new Blob([req.response], { type: type ? type : 'application/octet' });

                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {
                throw 'Empty or invalid response';
            }
        }
        req.send();
    } else {
        //fallback for browsers without blob saver
        throw 'Not implemented';
    }
}
```